# Find all possible products of elements in a list (in order) using parentheses

Tags: symbolic

In trying to learn Mathematica by solving problems as I study Abstract Algebra, I was trying to solve the following very simple problem.

Given a set `{x1, x2, ... , xN}`, find all possible products of all the elements in this set using parentheses.

So, for the set `{x1,x2, x3}`, the answer will be `{ (x1 . x2) . x3, x1 . (x2 . x3) }`

I create the list as follows :

```
listx[n_]:= Table[Subscript[x,i], {i, n}]
```

How do  I compute the possible products with parentheses ?

Comment: for `n=4`,  should  `m[m[x1, x2], m[x3,x4]]`  (i.e. `(x1. x2). (x3. x4)`) be included in the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each `n`, you obtain the new list of possibilities by multiplying each possibility for `n-1` once from the left and once from the right (modulo renaming of elements). I use `m[x,y]` to represent the parentheses.

```
listx = n \[Function] Thread[Subscript[x, Range[n]]];
step = a \[Function] With[{n = Max[Cases[a, _Integer, \[Infinity]]]},
    Join[
     Map[b \[Function] m[Subscript[x, 1], b], 
      a /. Thread[Range[1, n] -> Range[2, n + 1]]],
     Map[b \[Function] m[b, Subscript[x, n + 1]], a]
     ]
    ];
possibilities = n \[Function] Nest[step, {m @@ listx[2]}, n - 2];


possibilities[3]
```

[image]

```
possibilities[4]
```

[image]

**Edit**

kglr pointed me to an error in the implementation above. The code below uses a similar strategy by composing new possibilities from old ones, but now in an exhaustive way.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[1] = {Subscript[x, 1]};
f[2] = {m[Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2]]};
f[n_] := f[n] = Flatten[Table[
    Outer[m, 
     f[i], 
     f[n - i] /. Thread[Range[1, n - i] -> Range[i + 1, n]]],
    {i, 1, n - 1}]
   ]

f[4] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l} 
> > m\left(x_1,m\left(x_2,m\left(x_3,x_4\right)\right)\right) \\ 
> > m\left(x_1,m\left(m\left(x_2,x_3\right),x_4\right)\right) \\ 
> > m\left(m\left(x_1,x_2\right),m\left(x_3,x_4\right)\right) \\ 
> > m\left(m\left(x_1,m\left(x_2,x_3\right)\right),x_4\right) \\ 
> > m\left(m\left(m\left(x_1,x_2\right),x_3\right),x_4\right) \end{array}$

Surprisingly, this is also a bit quicker than using `Groupings`. (And it produces the same results (up to reordering)).

Answer (score 7):

In versions 11.0+, you can also use [Groupings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings.html):

```
ClearAll[groupings]
groupings[a_]:= Groupings[listx[#], {a -> 2}]&;

groupings[m][3] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  m\left(m\left(x_1,x_2\right),x_3\right) \\
>  m\left(x_1,m\left(x_2,x_3\right)\right) \\
> \end{array}$

```
groupings[m][4] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  m\left(m\left(m\left(x_1,x_2\right),x_3\right),x_4\right) \\
>  m\left(x_1,m\left(m\left(x_2,x_3\right),x_4\right)\right) \\
>  m\left(m\left(x_1,m\left(x_2,x_3\right)\right),x_4\right) \\
>  m\left(x_1,m\left(x_2,m\left(x_3,x_4\right)\right)\right) \\
>  m\left(m\left(x_1,x_2\right),m\left(x_3,x_4\right)\right) \\
> \end{array}$

**Note:** `groupings` contains elements that do not belong to the set produced by  Henrik's `possibilities`. For example, for `n = 4` it contains `m[m[x1, x2], m[x3,x4]]` which is not an element of `possibilities[4]`.

Comment: Very good point. My answer was a rather quick shot... =o/